# Send report only when the attachment has data in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008

Is there a way to configure SSRS (data-driven subscription?) to send reports in email only when the report contains data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no official configuration for "not send if no data". But you can try [russch's workarounds](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bimusings/archive/2005/07/29/445080.aspx). You can also find useful suggestions in comments. I prefer the raise error trick:

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RAISERROR('No data', 16, 1)
```